# Proper database modeling for many-to-many relationship between records

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling

all I building a small database application and I could use some input on the best approach to create a relationship between my tables.
[image: Driver Info]

I think I have it figured out but I've been staring at it so long I need a second set of eyes and opinions.

This model is for a race car driver. Where I am stuck in setting the relationship is on the Division table. Basically a driver can be in multiple divisions. To account for this I have added a DriverDivision table which is basically a lookup that allows me to map a driver to multiple divisions.

You can see from the model off of the driver there is a `PointsStanding` and a `RaceResults` table as well. This are associated to the driver as 1:M. Where I am stumbling is I'll need to also filter results and standings by Division. Do I need to create lookup tables between Division and these two tables as well? Looking at the model I can get all the results through the DriverInfo page but I don't know if that is the right approach? Navigating this would would always return a full object so I could see all results as well as the drivers associated to it. Am I way off track or or is there a better model/pattern to follow? When I first started this model I thought the driver would be the primary point but it feels like Division may be. A driver has to be associated to a division, points and results are associated to the driver but I'll need to be able to view all points and all standings by division.

I'd appreciate any suggestions or advice.

-Cheers

Comment: In this model you should delete driverid from results and points and instead add driverdivisionid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your post, a racer rides in one of more races, and each race belongs to a division.

One question is, can a driver belong to a division but not participate in any races in that division?  Depending on the answer, you might not need a relation between Driver and Division.  A relation between RaceResult and Divison makes more sense.

So you'd get something like:

```
Driver -->> RaceResult <<-- Race
                       <<-- Division
```

It seems to me like you could calculate standing based on past RaceResults.  If that's true, I would not store standings in the database at all.  Storing a result that you could also calculate is bound to result in inconsistencies: for example, if some updates the race result, but not the standing.

Finally, your table structure seems very generic for an initial design.  I'd try to simplify it to the bare-bones information storage you need for the first version of your application.

Comment: This is a great point. I need to figure out how they track this. I don't think there is a scenario where a driver would be a part of a division but not race in it, however it may be possible. A race will run multiple divisions in a night. For what you propose would I not need to flip Race and division  such as Driver -->> RaceResult <<-- Division <<-- Race

Comment: In your example, the Division entry would be Race-specific.  Might be better to have a foreign key to both in the RaceResult table, I'll put the suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Ok I think I am close. Last comment, question. As I was thinking about this the other scenario is a race can run multiple divisions in a night, a (the same) driver can also be in multiple divisions of that race. So in a race the driver could enter and run in 3 different (or however many divisions) in a single night. Would this criteria change the suggested approach or would what you have proposed still support this?

Comment: That would work fine, a RaceResult has foreign keys to Driver, Division, and Race.  Your example would result in multiple rows for the same race and driver, but with a different division.

Answer (score 1):

first, what is DriverDivisionId for? I’m assuming your using it as a primary key for the combo of division/driver, but you can use both the DivisionId and DriverId as the primary key for this.

second, you can add the divisionId to the point standings and race results as well, then use both the driverId and divisionId to get the results for a specific division/racer combo

edit:

after thinking for a minute I think I would add one more table, a 'Race' table that will be a list of all races. There you would need a 'RaceId' to identify the race. Then you can store all the information about this race there (including division), and in the RaceResults table you would have your RaceId, DriverId, PositionFinished, PositionStarted, RacerPoints

Comment: I disagree with Giorgi, you shouldn't make extra fields for something that is solved by using a primary key. Each entry will be a primary key in the DriverDivision table as each DriverDivision combo will be unique. -- edit: and also, if you were to do this what happens when you want to add all of the data from one of those tables for a single racer? you'd now have to know every DriverDivisionId and do a separate query for each instead of just using the DriverId.

Comment: I like this idea but I think I still need an intermediate table between race and division. The reason being is that during a race multiple divisions will run. They are not one to one.